# docker build command failed, throw 'Invalid runtimeconfig.json [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.403/dotnet.runtimeconfig.json] : The document is empty'

Tags: docker, .net-core

Running docker build --no-cache --force-rm -f [DockerFile path] -t [imagename]:latest failed, throw 'Invalid runtimeconfig.json [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.403/dotnet.runtimeconfig.json] [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.403/dotnet.runtimeconfig.dev.json] : The document is empty'.

[CLI error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ypq4d.png)

```
PS C:\> docker --version
Docker version 20.10.21, build baeda1f
```

```
PS C:\> dotnet --version
7.0.100
```

```
PS C:\> dotnet --info
.NET SDK:
 Version:   7.0.100
 Commit:    e12b7af219

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19044
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.100\

Host:
  Version:      7.0.0
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       d099f075e4

.NET SDKs installed:
  2.1.602 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  3.1.425 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.408 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  6.0.403 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  7.0.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.22 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.31 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.22 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.31 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.22 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.31 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 7.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

the sdk folder contents:
[sdk folder contents:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZGnL.png)

'dotnet.runtimeconfig.json' is in correct folder:
[/dotnet.runtimeconfig.json:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyUGv.png)

the contents of dotnet.runtimeconfig.json:

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "net6.0",
    "framework": {
      "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
      "version": "6.0.11"
    },
    "configProperties": {
      "System.Reflection.Metadata.MetadataUpdater.IsSupported": false
    }
  }
}
```

Running docker build should create the docker image (as previousely works fine!) but throw the above error at restoring stage.

Comment: I tried uninstalling and re-installing all dotnet sdks (using VS installer, Windows app & feature and I dotnet core uninstall tool to uninstall). Also inspected environment path for miss dotnet addressing, but none of these could solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the source of the issue. The problem is not in the SDK installation, nor the Visual Studio. I found the issue in 'Docker Desktop'. For me using 'Reset to factory defaults' button in troubleshoot, solve the issue!

Docker Desktop version = 4.15.0 (93002).

[image: Reset to factory defaults]